# Manually Run SSIS Package from Server "failed to load dts.dll"

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

On our new server, when I try to run the SSIS packages from Integration Services in SSMS (ie by right clicking on the package and selecting "run")
I get the following error

```
The program has failed to Load the library "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dts.dll"
```

Odd - the dll file is at that address, the SQLAgent login (under which integration services and Sql Agent runs) has permission to execute the file, and I have permission to execute the file (meaning we both have full control on the folder containing the dll). I can't see any reason why integration services wouldn't be able to load the library

This happens with all packages on the server

Stopping and restarting services (SQL and SSIS) has not resolved the issue

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried testing all of your data sources to make sure it can still point to everything necessary?

Comment: Data sources are not the problem - that file it says it is unable to load is component of the basic engine that executes SSIS packages - it doesn't get far enough to worry about data sources. I'm struggling to think of any other relevant detail to give! Except actually - I should have said that these packages execute within BIDS, and within jobs without any problem.

Comment: Can you post your PATH environment variable? Sometimes the order in which paths are placed in there can throw you off.

Comment: As a quick test, remove all SSIS-related paths from your PATH variable except the path in question and then try to execute it.

Comment: You could use dependency walker to check the dependencies of that DLL. Maybe that DLL requires another that doesn't exist. But regardless it should work with a new install. To clairify: you are running this from SSMS on the server?

Comment: Kyle - Path variable as follows     %SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem; %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\; C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\; C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\

Comment: Llama - thanks yes I am running this from SSMS on the server. I'll check out dependency walker

Comment: Very odd- I removed and readded the DTS references in the PATH variable and it now works fine. Must have been a typo in there I guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: gah - should've saved the "before" of the path variable. Zipping between too many jobs and didn't think think to keep it after I got it working.